# How to check if object doesn't exist in array in Swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift

I should compare MenuArray array, SavedArray array.

If MenuArray does not contain SavedArray's object, should remove SavedArray's object.

So I did.

```
for i in 0..<savedArr.count {
    let savedDic = savedArr[i]
    let containIndex = menuArray.index(where: { (dic) -> Bool in
        if dic[Keys.KEY_DISPETT_SEQ] as! Int == savedDic[Keys.KEY_DISPETT_SEQ] as! Int {
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    })

    if containIndex == nil {
        savedArr.filter({ (dic) -> Bool in
            return true
        })
    }
}
```

But it's not working.

How can I do?

Comment: `filter` returns an array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter to clean this up a bit.

```
var menuArray = [1,2,3,4,5,7]
var savedArray = [1,3,4,5,6]

for item in savedArray {
    savedArray = menuArray.filter { $0 != item }
}

print(savedArray) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

6 isn't present in `menuArray`, so it is removed from the `savedArray`.